# how to solve ftp error 450

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to get Ftp File using Timer(internal 15 seconds)

but my program will not run properly and then Return error is below

"The remote server returned an error: (450) File unavailable (e.g., file busy)"

this is my code.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//interval 15000
            GetFtpFile();
        }

private void GetFtpFile()
        {
            label1.Text = "File Name : ";
            label2.Text = "Process result : ";
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
            FtpUrl += date;
            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FtpUrl);
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("root", "pass");
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string lastModified = response.LastModified.ToString();

                    List<string> FileName = new List<string>();

                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        FileName.Add(streamReader.ReadLine().Split('/')[1]);
                    }
                    FileName.Sort();
                    if(FileName[FileName.Count-1].Equals(WriteFile) == false)
                    {
                        WriteFile = FileName[FileName.Count - 1];
                        label1.Text = "FileName : " + WriteFile;
                        using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                        {
                            wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("root", "pass");
                            byte[] FileData = wc.DownloadData(FtpUrl + @"\"+WriteFile);
                            using(FileStream fs = File.Create(di.FullName + @"\" + WriteFile))
                            {
                                fs.Write(FileData,0,FileData.Length);
                                fs.Close();

                            }
                            label2.Text = "Process result : Success";
                        }
                    }
                    streamReader.Close();
                    response.Close();

                }




            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _log.LogWrite(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how to fix a 450 Ftp Error:

1. Start your computer and log on as an administrator.
2. Click the Start button then select All Programs, Accessories, System
   Tools, and then click System Restore.
3. In the new window, select "Restore my computer to an earlier time"
   option and then click Next.
4. Select the most recent system restore point from the "On this list,
   click a restore point" list, and then click Next.
5. Click Next on the confirmation window.
6. Restarts the computer when the restoration is finished.